# How can ISP's block a website specific content while using encrypted connection?

Tags: tls, http, url-redirection

I'm learning about encryption and SSL certificates and I'm wondering: *If an encrypted connection is used when connecting to a website using a SSL certificate, how can ISP/company manager/government (whoever controls the network traffic) block **some** specific content of that website?*.

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) that an entire website/domain(IP address) *can* be blocked since the server IP is not encrypted at the TCP layer, otherwise no way to make a connection!. But since an encrypted connection is established, **all** data traffic is encrypted - including the request headers (like URL header) -, So ISP's don't know if the request is for

```
https://www.example.com/good-content
```

or for

```
https://www.example.com/bad-content
```

because the entire URL is encrypted along with the entire request to the receptionist.

My problem now is, **how could some ISP's block *some* videos on YouTube about 4 years ago?**.

I wasn't aware of something called encryption 4 years ago to think about it, but now I'm trying to understand what was going on that time.

The only Explanation I could come up with Is that YouTube was allowing `http` requests [at that time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28086867) . So an `http` request to

```
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bad-content
```

can be blocked , but a an `https` request to the same URL can not be blocked because the ISP doesn't know what is being watch!. I don't know if my explanation is right or wrong, but I hope I can understand.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not possible (without breaking the encryption).

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind here:

1. **ISP requires certificates** from them to be installed on your computer prior to allowing you to access the net. In this dystopian environment (which does exist in some countries and many corporate networks), the ISP would require you add their certificate to your trusted root store before accessing network resources. When your request is made to https://someplace.com/any-content, a proxy performs a man-in-the-middle, decrypts the traffic, and re-encrypts it on the fly with the certificate for the root store.  This would allow them to decrypt traffic and perform a MITM to inspect your traffic.
2. **ISP Blocks domain names** ISPs can block and filter DNS requests to somesite.com at will. Granted, this would block https://somesite.com/good-content and https://somesite.com/bad-content as well.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean like the [fiddlerRoot certificate](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/FirefoxHTTPS) that you install if you want to debug a `https` connection using fiddler ?

Comment: That's an example, because it does decryption on-the-fly like #1 above. However, I am not sure of the specifics about fiddler. Since it's so popular, I would imagine that it generates its own cert upon installation (trivial to do) otherwise, hackers would use that for all their attacks. It would be more obvious if you had to "install software" in order to access an ISP's network. In the late 90's, US ISPs had software you installed to access their networks, which (mostly) registered your Mac address, which is why routers have a mac address masquerade feature. So, the practice is not unheard of

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer about youtube 4 years ago, I can talk about SSL/TLS.

When you open a TLS connection to a server you may (and usually do) specify what name you are trying to reach, this is called [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

So your ISP knows:

- the IP you are connecting to, and
- the name you are trying to connect to.

The full URL (as you said) is encrypted, but knowing the servername may be enough censor the full site.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. So does this mean that if a website (You Tube for example) uses `https` exclusively, no one -in the middle- can know which content/video the users are watching?

Comment: @Accountant that is correct.